# controlling sort order of json output in Ruby on Rails (Ruby 1.8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, debugging, rubygems

Is there any way to convert a ruby array/hash structure to JSON AND specify the output order of the elements?

Having the actually order of the elements vary is not functionally important, BUT it just makes debugging tough... It would be nicer if I could somehow specify the tag order to the json output, so the human reading the json can easily find the tag they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No browsers do not guarantee sort order of objects. If you need sort order you need to use an indexed array.

Comment: As I said in the question... I understand that there is NO FUNCTIONAL purpose to my request.  By definition a hash has no sort order.   The question is can you for the purpose of easing debug force ruby to impose an order on the hash as its converted to JSON.   So for example {"foo": 123, "baz": 777, "ralph": 999} is equal to {"baz": 777, "ralph": 999, "foo": 123}  .  THAT IS UNDERSTOOD.  But it would be very nice if when the JSON is emitted that the order of the keys can be specified.